# How can I update cells in a collection view?

Tags: ios, swift, view, uicollectionview, refresh

I have mainview. This main view has two subviews, one for the Shop, and one for the purchased items which is a collection view that adds cells with the numberOfItemsInSection function. The number of cells is equal to purchasedItems array.count. When I buy an item from the shop, the array.count changes and that adds more cells to the collection view.

My problem is that the program doesn't automaticaly add more cells to the collection view when I buy this from the shop, but when I reload the main view.

So how can I immediately update/refresh the number of cells without reloading the main view?

Comment: Call `reloadData` or `insertItems` on the collection view.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to add the item to the array. then the insert item on collection view using

```
func insertItems(at indexPaths: [IndexPath])
```

Example :

```
itemarray.append(newItem)
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: itemarray.count-1, section: 0)
myCollectionView.insertItems(at: [indexPath])
```